# slickgrid - grid.getDataItem(0), dataView.getItem(0) and .dataView.getItemByIdx(0) returning reference

Tags: slickgrid

I'm trying to duplicate a row, but change like one column.

So I do something like this:

```
var item = myGrid.grid.getDataItem(rowIndex); 

item.id=123;

myGrid.dataView.addItem(item);
```

My issue is that if I am duplicating the row at index 0, when I do:

item.id = 123;

It actually makes id of the row at index 0 as 123 as well as the new line.

Is there a way to get the data and not get the actual reference to the row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would use the jQuery [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method to create a new object:

```
var newItem =  {};
$.extend(newItem, item);
newItem.id=123;
myGrid.dataView.addItem(newItem);
```